# Google Maps Embed API Failure

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I can't seem to get my Google Maps Embed iframe to work correctly and am completely lost...

Sometimes the iframe will zoom into the correct query location "Hilton Boston Downtown 89 Broad St, Boston MA 02110" and other times it will be entirely zoomed out and show the globe. I assume it means that it wasn't able to correctly find the address, but I have no idea why... Can anyone help?

```
<iframe 
width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" 
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Hilton+Boston+Downtown/Faneuil+Hall,+89+Broad+St,+Boston,+MA+02110,+United+States&amp;key=AIzaSyAJHvZiuT2J60Yw6qCULpYaUPo4v-uelUg">
</iframe>
```

Here's a JSFiddle with the iframe code: https://jsfiddle.net/zhxjn5q9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the embed api is currently broken for that address, using the [wizard](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start) gives me the same result.

You might try replacing the `+`'s in the URL with `%20`'s (or URL encoding the query string).

Some addresses do work (like "89 Broad St, Boston, MA 02110").

Comment: I think the conversion from +'s to %20s fixed it!

Thank you!